# Nested post routing express

Tags: node.js, express, post, routes

I have following  post

```
router.post('/auth',oauth.oAthmiddleware, function(req, res) {
    oauth.auth;
});
```

It reutrns access token and other details

I have another post

```
router.post('/refreshToken', function(req, res,next) {
    var username = 'change';
    var password = 'change';
    req.body.username = username;
    req.body.password = password;
   // call '/auth' post
});
```

In above I have changed and called the above post and want to return response from inner post

How can I implement the same

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
router.post('/refreshToken', function(req, res,next) {
    req.url = '/auth'
    ...
    req.body.password = password;

    return router._router.handle(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: How will it handle oauth.oAthmiddleware

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam it will pass the same header if you want to update header, update req.header with auth token before forwarding.

Comment: not header, please see my exmple in question, in /auth post there is middleware,

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam it will call it anyway, did you try that?

Comment: I got it, let I think its working, I will mark it as answered, one question, is this a good practice, or any other professional approach

Comment: TBH, it's not :) client should do it on the basis of response from one end point.

Comment: My scenario is I have written custom logic to generate access token and refresh token, Now I am using same logic to regenerate access token and refresh token when user try to use refresh token to regenerate

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way, because this is my first node app

Comment: yes there are many ways, you can also use `res.redirect('<route>');`

Comment: this is just matter of redirect, I meant to say any professional way that I am not aware of it,

Comment: then you can make common function for both

Comment: Yes that will be again same. I think I am not able to explain my wish, anyway thanks